# Testing the difference of the mean of the subgroups of the 2 groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, paired-data

there are participants who are applied 2 different treatment methods. I tested whether these Treatment methods are effective or not with a paired sample t test, but what statistical analysis should I use to test whether the treatment method differs?

So basically i'd like to if the treatment methods differs?

Below there is an image of the dataset.

[image]